# JavaFx buttons click in order then play

Tags: javafx

I am looking to have buttons play in the order in which they are clicked. For example, if I click buttons 3, 4, and 6 I would like to then click a "play" button and this button then clicks the same pattern I clicked.

Comment: You definitely need to rephrase.

Comment: Describe what "the button clicks" means. Are you attempting to manipulate the cursor, animate a sequence highlighting some buttons, simply trigger some event handers for the buttons or ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a crude example of how to implement this. [`TimeLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) and [`SequentialTransitions`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html) are the key. Comments are in the code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.SequentialTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication57 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        List<ToggleButton> order = new ArrayList();//The buttons will be added to see ArrayList as they are pressed. ArrayList maintains order

        ToggleButton btn4 = new ToggleButton();
        btn4.setText("btn4");
        btn4.setOnAction(actionEvent ->
        {
            btn4.setSelected(false);//When you selected a ToggleButton it stays pressed until it is pressed again. So we use code to unpress it.
            order.add(btn4);
        });

        ToggleButton btn3 = new ToggleButton();
        btn3.setText("btn3'");
        btn3.setOnAction(actionEvent ->
        {
            btn3.setSelected(false);//When you selected a ToggleButton it stays pressed until it is pressed again. So we use code to unpress it.
            order.add(btn3);
        });

        ToggleButton btn2 = new ToggleButton();
        btn2.setText("btn2");
        btn2.setOnAction(actionEvent ->
        {
            btn2.setSelected(false);//When you selected a ToggleButton it stays pressed until it is pressed again. So we use code to unpress it.
            order.add(btn2);
        });

        ToggleButton btn1 = new ToggleButton();
        btn1.setText("btn1");
        btn1.setOnAction(actionEvent ->
        {
            btn1.setSelected(false);//When you selected a ToggleButton it stays pressed until it is pressed again. So we use code to unpress it.
            order.add(btn1);
        });

        Button btnPlay = new Button("play");
        btnPlay.setOnAction(actionEvent ->
        {
            List<Timeline> timeLines = new ArrayList();//This List will hold the TimeLines so that it can be used later to play the animation in order.

            for (ToggleButton tempToggleButton : order)//Create a press animation and a release animation for each ToggleButton in the List order
            {
                KeyFrame pressButton = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),
                        (kfActionEvent) ->
                {
                    System.out.println(tempToggleButton.getText() + "Selected!");
                    tempToggleButton.setSelected(true);
                });
                Timeline pressTimeline = new Timeline();
                pressTimeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(pressButton);
                timeLines.add(pressTimeline);

                KeyFrame releaseButton = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),
                        (kfActionEvent) ->
                {
                    System.out.println(tempToggleButton.getText() + "Unselected!");
                    tempToggleButton.setSelected(false);
                });
                Timeline releaseTimeline = new Timeline();
                releaseTimeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(releaseButton);
                timeLines.add(releaseTimeline);
            }

            SequentialTransition sequentialTransition = new SequentialTransition();
            sequentialTransition.getChildren().addAll(timeLines);//Add all the Timelines created to a SequentialTransition
            sequentialTransition.play();
            sequentialTransition.setOnFinished(stActionEvent -> {
                timeLines.clear();//Once done, clear the animations
            });

        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btnPlay);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: this worked for the most part but now I am trying to set a different action for each button. for example a certain sound, is it possible for me to just use the order array list and call it like so; order.fire(); ? Instead of printing out the selected or unselected outputs @SedrickJefferson

Comment: If this answer solved your original question, except it as the answer. If you have a new problem, try to tackle it first. If you are still having a problem after trying to solve it yourself, feel free to ask a new question on a new thread.

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code makes it looks like the button was pressed

```
button.arm();
PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(0.5));
pause.setOnFinished(e -> {
    button.disarm();
});
pause.play();
```

If you want the button to actually fire not just look like it did then add `button.fire();` after the `button.disarm();`

Then you just need to record the buttons that are pressed