# JavaFX Button "Animation"

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making a Simon game and everything is working fine except for one thing, the "lights" who needs to be pressed by the player are all glowing at the same time so the player doesn't have any idea which one glowed first. I tried to put a "`thread.sleep()`" after a color glows to pause the UI for one second, but it wasn't working and was a bad idea anyway. Here is the loop where the colors are supposed to "glow".

```
for (int i = 0; i < Colorslist.size(); i++) {
    if (Colorslist.get(i) == 0) {
        vbutton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #00ff00; ");
            //Here the button change color and I want it to stay 
            //like this for 1 second before swapping it with the ancient color.
...
```

If a for loop is not a good way to what I want to do please tell me, Thank you.

Comment: You could try [Sequential Transition](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/basics.htm#CJAJJAGI).

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668768/javafx-buttons-click-in-order-then-play/47677123#47677123) is something similar that can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFx buttons click in order then play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668768/javafx-buttons-click-in-order-then-play)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an altered version of the code I linked to.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.SequentialTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class Simon extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn1 = new Button(" 1 ");
        Button btn2 = new Button(" 2 ");
        Button btn3 = new Button(" 3 ");
        Button btn4 = new Button(" 4 ");

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.add(btn1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        gridPane.add(btn2, 1, 0, 1, 1);
        gridPane.add(btn3, 0, 1, 1, 1);
        gridPane.add(btn4, 1, 1, 1, 1);

        //Create Transistion
        Random random = new Random();
        List<Integer> buttonOrder = new ArrayList();
        int numberOfButtonsToLightUpInOneSeq = 5;//This determines the length of the color sequence
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfButtonsToLightUpInOneSeq; i++)//This determines the color sequence
        {
            buttonOrder.add(random.nextInt(4));
        }

        List<Timeline> timelines = new ArrayList();//This list will hold the Timelines
        for (Integer seq : buttonOrder)//Create a show color animation and a clear color animation for each Button depending on the sequence
            {
                KeyFrame colorButton = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),
                        (kfActionEvent) ->
                {
                    switch(seq)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            btn1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            btn2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            btn3.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            btn4.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
                            break;
                    }
                });

                Timeline showColor = new Timeline();//create the timeline
                showColor.getKeyFrames().addAll(colorButton);//add the frame to the Timeline
                timelines.add(showColor);//add the timeline to the list of timelines

                KeyFrame removeColorFromButton = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),
                        (kfActionEvent) ->
                {
                    switch(seq)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            btn1.setStyle(null);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            btn2.setStyle(null);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            btn3.setStyle(null);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            btn4.setStyle(null);
                            break;
                    }
                });
                Timeline removeColor = new Timeline();//Create the Timeline
                removeColor.getKeyFrames().addAll(removeColorFromButton);//Add the frame to the Timeline
                timelines.add(removeColor);//Add the time line to the list of Timelines
            }
        //Runs the List of Timeline sequentially
        SequentialTransition sequentialTransition = new SequentialTransition();
            sequentialTransition.getChildren().addAll(timelines);//Add all the Timelines created to a SequentialTransition
            sequentialTransition.play();
            sequentialTransition.setOnFinished(stActionEvent -> 
            {
                timelines.clear();//Once done, clear the animations
            }
        );




        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(gridPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```